# How to stream audio data from Android to WebSocket server?

Tags: android, kotlin, websocket

I've working on RTC mobile app. I have a nodejs server over a WebSocket connection - I got the connection. But I'm really confusing about how to stream audio in kotlin. MediaCodec or AudioRecord? I've ready the docs, but I confess I don't know how to proceed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've considered working with webRTC and it did a great job. As I was using react native, things get more painless. Broadcast audio in pure websocket API, is a distressing work. Use webRTC as I did and I hope you'll be happy.